# Python: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get': Lambda + Map

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to do this: my dictionary and operation:

```
dict = {'a': {'b': 2}}
```

Assigned value in this dictionary: now calculating this dict

```
dict(map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), dict))
```

But I am getting error, after entering above line code:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What is wrong in that?

Comment: Is `dict` a variable or a function?  Don't reuse the names of built in functions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using `map` here. Iterating over a dictionary gives you the keys only, which are strings. Just use the dict directly; you don't need `lambda` either:

```
my_dict.get('a').get('b')
```

(As noted in the comments, you shouldn't use `dict` as the name of your variable.)

Answer (score 0):

When you access a dictionary `d` as an iterator, you iterate over the keys.  You are essentially doing

```
dict(map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), ['a']))
```

Comment: Same ERROR:   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Chandni here he is trying to tell you what you were doing before.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is wrong. You can't pass a dictionary to `lambdas` in Python and get the desired result. Instead of performing any operations let's just see what is happening here.

```
>>> dict = {'a': {'b': 2}}
>>> map(lambda x: x, dict)
['a']
```

So you can see that, the value of `x` which is being passed to `lambda` is `['a']`, not our original dictionary. This is because when you pass a dictionary as an iterator, you iterate over `keys`. To support this, try this.

```
>>> map(lambda x: x, {1: 'a', 3: 'c'})
[1, 3]
```

Another alternative you can think of is passing like `keyword arguments`. Let's try that for lambdas and use `map` to get the desired result.

```
>>> map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), **dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: map() takes no keyword arguments
```

Oops, in this case `map()` has a problem dealing with keyword arguments.

So you can use alternative ways like following mentioned.

```
>>> dict.get('a').get('b')
2
>>> dict['a']['b']
2
```

Also, try avoiding variable names which matches some inbuilt function names.

Comment: your first sentence:  map(lambda x: x, dict)

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
`

Comment: @Chandni did you initialised the dictionary before that, and if you used any another variable name instead, pass that.

Comment: And this is just a simple example I have used here, my code is having 2-3 keys with multiple dictionaries. dict.get('a').get('b'), this is working, I know. I want to make it work with Lambda. By Using simple lambda it will giving this: `lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), d
(<function <lambda> at 0x7fd7e52d7500>, {'a': {'b': 2}})`

Comment: ..... but using map, it will map with that and wont give that function <lambda> ... thanks for your answer, but it is not helping me. :(

Comment: @Chandni if you want to use `lambda`, you can do `map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), [dict])` which makes a list and that dictionary as it's element. That will work. A similar approach is also mentioned in answer by @bouletta.

Answer (score -2):

here is the doc on map :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Try :

```
map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), (dict,))
```

Comment: To convince yourself that dictionaries are iterables, try `for i in d: print(i)`  You'll print all the keys in dictionary `d`

Comment: Ok my phrasing was bad. Dictionaries are iterable yes. But in this case his syntax means you are mapping on the keys of the dictionary hence the error.

In this case his x is a dictionary key, which happens to be a string. I doubt this is what he wanted.

Comment: Hi, Bouletta, Yours is the best answer I found, M getting answer:................. `>>> map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), (d,)) 
[2] ` Getting answer by this: but this is not working with Dictionary () :......... `>>> dict(map(lambda x:x.get('a').get('b'), (d,)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
` I want result in dictionary.

Comment: I'm don't really understand what you want your output to be. Here your lambda function takes a dictionary (d) and returns d.get('a').get('b) which in your example is an integer.

I guess my question is if you want a dictionary as a result, what do you want it to contain (using your example) ?